# close ng-select when a particular value is select

Tags: angular

I have a ng-select box. I don't want the user to select any other value when a specific value for example `x` is selected in the `ng-select` and so if the user needs to select any other value, he must clear that value first.

I have a special value in the list of `ng-option`. The requirement is that special value should be selected alone and so if a user tries to select some other value he should not be able to do it and must clear that value first.

```
<ng-select [hideSelected]="true" [loading]="isLoading" [multiple]="true"
           [(ngModel)]="ids" [closeOnSelect]="false" #selectedNames="ngModel" required
           placeholder="{{'Names' | translate}}" [clearable]="true">
           <ng-container *ngFor="let name of names">
                        <ng-option *ngIf="showOption">{{name.Label}}</ng-option>
           </ng-container>
</ng-select>
```

Comment: What happen when the user selects the non-special value, then selects the special value? Do you automatically clear the non-special value?

Comment: yes in that case I want to clear the non-special value.

Comment: Sure. On top of using `(change)="onChange($event)"` like Ghaith mentioned, you can also use `close()` to close the select. Please let me know if you need that example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following solution:

Suppose, for example, that the **ng-select** contains the values from 1 to 5 and the specific value equal to 3. We will add a method that allows to test if the value selected by the user equals the specific value or not . This method will be bound by the '(change)' event of **ng-select**.

The TypeScript code:

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
selectedValues = [];
specificValue = 3;

onChangeNgSelect(event) {
  if (event.filter(value => value === this.specificValue).length) {
    this.selectedValues = [event[event.length - 1]];
  }
}
```

The HTML code:

```
<ng-select [hideSelected]="true" [multiple]="true" (change)="onChangeNgSelect($event)"
             [(ngModel)]="selectedValues" [closeOnSelect]="false" required
             [clearable]="true">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let value of values">
    <ng-option [value]="value">{{ value }}</ng-option>
  </ng-container>
</ng-select>
```

Demo:

You can select all values at the same time except the specific value 3:

[image]

If the specific value 3 is selected, all other values will be eliminated and vice versa :

[image]

If the specific value 3 is selected and another value is selected at the same time, the value 3 will be eliminated and replaced by the selected value :

[image]

You can inspire from this example for your task :)